# how about an "I survived the rep recalc 2010" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, reputation-recalc

how about a new bronze badge showing the loss of rep in the rep recalc of 2010?

Comment: Mine would have a negative number.

Comment: How about a badge for not asking a question on MSO about the recalc.

Comment: What constitutes "survival"? ;)

Comment: This is what I get for smart-ass remarks in question form :)

Comment: Would the downvoters please let me know what I did wrong?  This questions seems to be getting some attention, wouldn't a -2 be dead with no activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhmm ... let me think, ... no.

Answer (score 8):

How about we all accept it's a good for the community as a whole?

Besides, what would the badge say for all the people that had their reputation boosted because they are good answerers and didn't get their reputation from asking questions?

The prize is a better reputation system for all of us, we need nothing more.

Comment: Ironically, we both got this badge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904?tab=votes#tab-top (Good Question and Enlightened are silver instead of bronze though.)

Comment: @gnome, I don't think I got Enlightened for that post, perhaps because it got edited a lot by you

Comment: I just accepted it, do you have to wait a bit?

Comment: oh, ok, I thought it got accepted before...

Comment: It always seemed like it would be the best answer, that's why I edited it as updates and clarifications came in, but didn't want to accept it initially in case someone else came up with something better, then forgot.

Comment: @gno, I just got what you were trying to do (create a question to point the dupes that were coming in the near future), and tried to help you

Comment: I bet Jon Skeet's rep went _up_ by more than all but, say the top percentile of users :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't want to discourage you from suggesting improvements and additions to the SO sites, but this one does not rank well when considered against the purpose of badges.

Badges are to encourage good behaviour on the sites - what good behaviour would such a badge encourage? Less whinging, perhaps? Of course, there's no way to measure that so the badge would be hard to reward without manual intervention.

That said, you might sell a t-shirt or two if it carried this slogan.

Answer (score 4):

Sure -- but you should only get it if, during the recalc, your rep goes up instead of down.  Sort of a retroactive award for acting in accordance with the best interests of the site despite the previous equal weight toward questions and answers.

Comment: The downside is that it would mainly be given to the people who have enough badges already due to the fact that the rep system is now sane.

Comment: What is this "enough badges" that you speak of?  Oh, you mean more than 0?

Comment: No. I mean more that me ;)

Comment: Asking questions on SO is not in accordance with the best interests of the site?

Answer (score 3):

How about an "I got a badge" badge?  We'll just give one to everyone because, hey, new badge, right?

Comment: Does this mean the requirements for [Generalist] will be "does not have any badges"?

Comment: Would this badge be awarded when you get the "I got a badge" badge?

Comment: @Downvoter: You're thinking of the [Tautology] badge, awarded for earning the [Tautology] badge.

Comment: @mmy, I was thinking recursion and a way to have infinite badges, but that's good too...

Comment: I hope this badge is only awarded once.