# Please be kind to newcomers

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)

I want to protest about how my recent duplicate question related to the grand reputation recalculation has been answered by some people here.

Some people like Jeff Yates and Voyager have been both polite and helpful.

Others like Hop and Downvoter have answered aggressively, as if posting a duplicate question on this hot topic was a deliberately offensive or blatantly lazy move of mine.

Yet I did all that looked reasonably possible to me to avoid posting a duplicate question. Yet none of the answers to related questions I've read mentioned the grand reputation recalculation. And I failed to see the banner on the form (not big enough, not the place where I tend to look for answers, either).

So please, may I remind you to be kind to newbies and assume good faith? If you were an occasional SO user and didn't know there was an ongoing grand reputation recalculation and you saw your score drop suddenly – how do you think you would react?

Comment: Also, it would help is this banner was proeminently present on all sites there the recomputation occurs. There is no such banner on SO !

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs

Comment: Voted to close! **Bwahahahahah!**

Comment: @fred-hh You have a point with what you say in your comment IMO. But I'm awfully tempted to vote for this question as a duplicate ;)

Comment: "Yet none of the answers to related questions I've read mentioned the grand reputation recalculation" <- Really?

Comment: @Downvoter: Maybe he's blind and his screen reader is broken, and he navigated to Meta and posted a question on muscle memory alone?

Comment: As they say, the customer is always wrong. If a user can't find something or figure something out, it can't possibly be due to the site design - it must be a defective user.

Comment: @Pekka please go :-) whi'le we're at it ;-)

Comment: @Downvoter: please read my previous comments in both questions, try to reproduce what I've done, and you'll have a chance to understand.

Comment: @fred: I understand, but now, thanks to your duplicate question, another user that might use a similar wording as yours will find your question and see a valid link to an answer.

Comment: @voyager: except that my duplicate question has been deleted by now... oh well. But thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @fred: as I told you in another thread, I disagree with the closing. It would be interesting to learn what the reason was (there might be a very valid one).

Comment: @voy, Jeff surely deleted all of them, they were quite time-localized and there were dozens

Comment: @Downvoter, it was Kyle, and now I understand why, but I would have left them hanging around for a day or two to give every late comer a chance to see them. (The different wordings help to increase their likelihood of them being seen.)

Comment: @voyager: for my enlightment, what was the reason for deleting it ?

Comment: @fred: all those questions where starting to take a fairly large amount of "space" on the front page. As soon as one Meta moderator considered that no new questions would appear, he started deleting most of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation to understand what is the reason.

There has been an influx of people like yourself to complain about the loss of rep points.

If you look on top of your question you'll see a banner already [explaining what you were asking](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/), as well as if you had looked at either the [question tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) or the [front page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) you would have learnt [what the problem was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010).

Also, you've done it again (not [looking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nice+to+new) before asking), as this has been a [hot topic before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs).

Comment: I'm sorry, this banner is not visible enough. Also, for some reason I did not come here through the front page. And all this not in my mind excuse incivility. If people are too tired to answer such questions they can use prewritten answers or leave the task to others.

Comment: @fred: prewritten answers == close as duplicate

Comment: And there is a good reason I didn't look at the list of top questions: I didn't realize my topic was a hot topic, so I contended myself to read the answers to similar questions. None had the right answer.

Comment: @Downvoter: I know and it's legitimate and logical. But at least you and many others have read me be now. That was the goal.

Comment: @fre: We blame Jeff for not posting this banner last week on Stack Overflow and for not posting the orange banner after the rep recalc for each user. Nevertheless try to be less thin-skinned.

Comment: @John Smithers: agreed, thank you. As for not posting the banner on SO, nobody's perfect. But too bad some people (e.g. Downvoter above) don't seem to understand the practical implications of that.

Comment: @voyager "you've done it again (not looking before asking)": yes and no. No, not "again": first time I really looked up, but ended up looking in the wrong places for reasons I've explained elsewhere. Second time, yes, I wanted to protest and that my protest be clearly visible, even knowing it would be (legitimately) downvoted as not-a-question. (It didn't occur to my mind it would be a duplicate.)

Comment: @Downvoter "prewritten answers == close as duplicate" I had not understood you when I answered you on this, now I understand what you mean. I don't mind the closing. I mind the tone of words used to answer. Using a prewritten answer when closing a question is better than using harsh words to rebuke the poster.