# Sudden drop of reputation for no reason on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

A few days ago I noticed a sudden drop in my reputation points (from 640 to 420). I have looked at the summary page but nothing was mentioned there.

Can anyone please tell me the reason?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010

Comment: So underwent a SQL Injection Cross site scripting XSS attack in which reputation of some random users was stolen.

Comment: @LadybugKiller You're a higher-up in terms of rep at the very least (and in this thread, so I can ping you). Is the preceding comment by becomingGuru, um, accurate? Thanks.

Comment: @Matt - no, he's joking.

Comment: @Matt: You misused the comment system for private messaging? Tsk, tsk, tsk ;) Dominic is right, Guru is joking.

Comment: I knew that wasn't what happened, I just though came off a little too deadpan to be a joke. At any rate, thanks.

Comment: ^ \*thought it came off\*