# My reputation points in stackoverflow has suddenly gone down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

My reputation points in stackoverflow has suddenly gone down from over 2400 it got to 1800, that does not get reflected in the reputation charts either.

Comment: See also - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this blog entry.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/

To summarise, questions were recalculated to give you 5 reputation instead if 10 for every up vote. This happened to every user.