# Rep cap kicking in a little too early?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I know there are a ton of existing questions about this, but they were all from before the [March 2010 Recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010) when the rules were changed, so I'm wondering if this might be a new bug.

Currently my rep history for today on Stack Overflow shows 21 votes and 3 acceptances, but only +235 rep, which means only +190 for upvotes and therefore only 19 were counted.

The top question also shows +40 rep for +5 votes, so the rep cap definitely kicked in somewhere.  I didn't issue any downvotes or do anything else that would have artificially lowered the cap.

Accepted answers are immune to rep cap now and downvotes/revoked upvotes are supposed to be compensated for by newer upvotes, so this looks like a bug to me.

Yes or yes?

[Proof http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3622/repcap.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3622/repcap.png)

**Addendum:** I actually did check the rep report, and Jeff's answer actually demonstrates quite clearly that this actually **is reproducible** - the total rep on the rep report adds up to 245, not 235.  There's definitely a bug *somewhere*.

Comment: Have you checked by clicking on the "today" link? You might have got 10 before the first time you logged in.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yep.  Proof is now attached.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43012#43012 or http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: Where is my big grey box on that page? Looks like you could draw in it. :(

Comment: How can this be [status-norepro]? You can easily verify that the screenshot is legit, and doesn't reflect reality, ergo there is a bug here somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, Jeff seems a little trigger-happy with the `status-norepro` and `status-bydesign` tags.  This is about as repro as it gets.

Comment: I love the `status-norepro-in-bizarro` tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case will be handled as part of [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), when a upvote is reversed that affected you rep cap, it will be adjusted accordingly within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to post this as a comment on Jeff's answer but it got too long...

By comparing the reputation audit with the screenshot, it would appear that the 'recent activity' list is cached in some way, and not refreshed with newer data.  One possible cause of the discrepancy in this case is that the OP received an upvote that was then retracted within the window, and then a subsequent upvote put him over the rep cap (but with the earlier vote retracted, he's back below it again.)

I can point to another example, that only developers would be able to see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/132636?StartDate=2010-03-12&EndDate=2010-03-12.

What happened here is a huge number of serial upvotes that were later removed -- however, the recent activity screen shows the state of the system *before* the recalculation.

[image: screenshot]

Reputation audit for 2010-03-12:

```
 2     37495 (10)
 2     37495 (10)
 2     29855 (10)
 2     42089 (10)
 2     42098 (10)
 2     42099 (10)
 1     42099 (15)
 2     42092 (10)
 2     42099 (10)
 2     42098 (10)
 2     42099 (10)
 2     42098 (10)
 2     42099 (10)
 2     42098 (10)
 2     42099 (10)
 2     42092 (10)
 2     42092 (10)
 2     42089 (10)
 2     42089 (10)
 3     42089 (-2)
-- 2010-03-12 rep +193  = 10005
```

Comment: This would make sense. If I had just one "revocation" after the rep cap was reached, and it didn't "undo" the cap, then I could have received, one, two, or a dozen more upvotes and still been stuck at 190.  Seems to be the only explanation for how **two** upvotes weren't counted.

Comment: @Aarobot: from Jeff's pasting of your reputation audit (http://stackoverflow/reputation), it looks like you did get credit for that last upvote; it's just that the "recent activity" page doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @Ether: Strange as it may sound, I didn't post this 'cause I was worried about my rep, I just saw what appeared to be a bug and thought I should report it. ;)

Comment: @Aarobot: I understand; I've been there too :)

Comment: @aaro basically what's written to the database gets out of sync due to chronology issues (deletions, unaccepts, etc). the /reputation page is always 100% correct because it does not rely on the values in the database -- it walks the history and calculates everything from scratch, from the beginning of time, every time.

Comment: @Jeff: I understand. I trust that the /reputation page is 100% correct. If it's out of sync with the rep page due to chronology issues then the rep page is bugged. According to rep-report I earned 245 for the day; did I actually *get* 245, as the report suggests, or only 235, as the rep history page suggests?  Either the page is wrong (including the total) or there's something important it's not telling me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you determined whether some of the upvoted questions are CW?

Are you sure all the votes are for "today"?

Comment: Yes and yes.  CW votes don't show up in this screen... or at least they never used to.  But all the questions show actual rep gain so they can't be CW, and the final question (the one that shows +40 for 5 votes) is definitely not CW.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://stackoverflow.com/reputation to validate.

I just did (developers, but *not* diamond moderators, have access to this per user) and it is showing me this for 4-14, for you:

```
 2   2619185 (10)
 2   2571516 (10)
 2   2520324 (10)
 1   2630271 (15)
 2   1911327 (10)
 2   2638692 (10)
 2   2638692 (10)
 2   2638692 (10)
 2   2638790 (10)
 2   2638919 (10)
 1   2604652 (15)
 2   2639564 (10)
 1   2639499 (15)
 2   2639499 (10)
 2   2639564 (10)
 2   2638919 (10)
 2   2639499 (10)
 2   2204535 (10)
 2   2640503 (10)
 2   2640503 (10)
 2   2640503 (10)
 2   2640503 (10)
 2   2640503 (10)
```

Comment: I did, actually - the points add up to 245, not 235.  So... how is this norepro?

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted one of your answers with one upvote?

Comment: I don't *think* I did... I don't see why I would have.  Possibly I deleted one that I thought was 0 and somebody upvoted at the exact same time?  I'm not sure how I would check.

Comment: @Aarobot, if you remember some texts related to that post or question, you may google it, sometimes, they have cache.

Comment: @Aaro, looks like I am assuming wrong, I found the one you deleted, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622340/object-of-type-customobject-cannot-be-converted-to-type-customobject/2622358#2622358), it does not have any upvotes.