# Reputation Recalculation - Reverse down votes as well?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

When reputation gets recalculated, do down vote loss in reputation also get reversed as up votes get reversed?

Comment: Do you mean the -1 loss as a voter, or the -2 loss as a votee?

Comment: Do you mean reputation lost (and gained) from posts that have now been deleted?

Comment: When I read this question originally, my brain automatically filled in what ChrisF suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.  This encourages deletion of bad answers, among other effects.

Comment: Source? Last I heard, reputation losses were not reversed.

Comment: _(This comment replaces my two earlier comments.)_  I've been searching for something to cite ever since I posted this answer, but I haven't been able to find anything.  What I can tell you is that I loaded up `stackoverflow.com/reputation` and manually checked every post for which I lost rep.  I'm not a 10k user there, and I know I deleted at least two posts with negative scores, but I was able to see every post for which I lost rep and they all had positive scores.  In the absence of rep recalc bugs or other unlikely cases, I believe that confirms my answer.

Comment: Source found: " __any__ reputation changes from questions and answers that have now been deleted will not affect your final reputation score" (emphasis mine) -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010/42905#42905