# Possible bug: are comment deletion and comment votes supposed to use the same backend?

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confirmation dialog for deleting a comment does not appear twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47293/confirmation-dialog-for-deleting-a-comment-does-not-appear-twice)

I got a comment on [this answer I posted earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47406/reputation-recalculation-reverse-down-votes-as-well).  I posted one quick reply comment, then another one a few minutes later with more information, and was about to post another follow-up minutes after that.  Instead, I decided to merge all three comments into one large comment.

So I posted the large comment — the only one that's visible to <10k users now — and went to delete the original two.  The first one went fine; I clicked the little red icon, got a "are you sure you want to delete" JS-type popup, selected OK and the comment went poof.  I then immediately clicked on the red icon for the second comment, and got the colored rectangular "you may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" popup.  After waiting five seconds, I clicked the red icon again, and the comment went away with no JS-style confirmation popup.

I see two potential bugs here: first, the system thought my deletion attempt was a vote attempt, and second, the system didn't give me a "confirm this deletion" choice.  I know comment votes aren't the most important thing, but it could be a symptom of another problem.  Is this the intended behavior?  "Not a bug" seems plausible to me, but it seemed odd enough to be worth reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deletion is in fact a vote.