# When I delete a comment, then try to delete another comment too quickly, the error message talks about comment votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-comments, warning

When I tried to delete a comment after I just deleted another one, the system told me

> You can *submit a comment vote* every five seconds.

The message should be different, right?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a comment is a vote to delete, as far as the computer knows.

Comment: Source: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47412/possible-bug-are-comment-deletion-and-comment-votes-supposed-to-use-the-same-bac/47416#47416

Comment: That's bad design, because to the user they are different, so the message is quite confusing.

Comment: @Ether Then open a feature request? I'm just reporting the current reasoning.

Comment: The message is confusing, but it's voting for almost every action -- such as voting to close your own question.

Comment: **You can't vote to delete your own comment, it just does it.**

Comment: If I try to delete a comment it is (seems to be?) deleted in the platform. Now, regardless of its implementation, shouldn't the error message "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" be more end-user friendly?

Comment: Presumably a site designed for computer programming questions would be able to differentiate between "how the computer sees it" and "how the user sees it".  Google Maps doesn't report travel distances in binary.