# Deleting comments in rapid succession produces improper error

Tags: bug, comments

SO rev. 2013.11.14.1155

I am not sure if this is on purpose or not but an incorrect error message seems to be appearing when deleting comments in rapid succession.

I have two comments:

[image]

So I deleted Comment #2 successfully and quickly went to delete Comment #1 and was greeted with this error message:

[image]

Comment: Loosely speaking, deleting a comment *might* be seen as a vote

Comment: @gparyani I'd think http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49268/212780 is a better duplicate target, no? He's not asking about the confirmation dialog.

Comment: No, this is by design (though I personally hate it).

Comment: Lots of info here: [Rate Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: Thanks @geobits and I agree with Ethers comment on that post