# redundant badges Nice/Good/Great

Tags: discussion, badges

If a question or answer has 10 upvotes a nice badge is awarded, 25 a good badge, and 100 great...once a higher badge is awarded the lower badge remains.  Therefore for each great answer one will also receive a nice and good badge.  Is it a bit redundant to get three similar badges for the same answer?

Instead of

```
> 10 = Nice
> 25 = Good
> 100 = Great
```

would it make more sense to change the existing badge instead of applying new badges?

```
10-24 = Nice
25-99 = Good
> 100 = Great
```

Edit: modified with correct values

Comment: Are you asking for **fewer** badges???

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not redundant.

- When a martial artist gets his black belt, does he burn the brown one?
- When a swimmer gets his white badge, does he have to give back the red?
- When a baseball team wins the World Series, does it throw away the pennants?

It's well-known that badges on the SO family are supposed to work the same way Achievements do in games.  And Achievements all work the same way - there's usually a series of them for doing the same thing, but at different levels/scores/etc., and you never lose previous ones.

Comment: Although I cant speak for swimming, the martial arts answer is yes.   In regards to baseball, youre talking about different seasons, while here we are talking about the same question/answer.  You might want to try some new analogys.. ie do you turn in your diploma once you get your degree?..etc..

Comment: @Locutus: What on earth are you talking about?  It's the same team, same season, the analogy is perfectly apt.  On the other hand, your diploma/degree analogy sucks because they'd be for different programs.  It *might* be applicable to keeping your Bachelor's degree after you get a Master's in the same subject, but I think 3 analogies were enough.

Comment: @Aarobot Youre right about the pennants, my bad.  Now after a team wins the World Series, why do you think they dont ever say NL/AL pennant champs?  Maybe because its inferred?  
In regards to my analogy, youre also right that it was almost as bad as the three you had provided, thanks for polishing it up.

Comment: @Locutus: It doesn't matter if they *talk* about it, they still *keep it*.  What part of this aren't you understanding?  Badges are cumulative rewards, not "upgradable" statuses.

Comment: @Aarobot What makes you think I dont understand?  Actually, lets take a step back, do you think Im for or against this?

Comment: @Locutus: You call these analogies bad based on a false premise, then come up with a "better" one that's entirely nonsensical.  Either you don't understand or you're being intentionally antagonistic.  And either way I refuse to waste any more time discussing it.

Comment: @Aarobot I did come up with one and you helped perfect it.  Dont beat yourself up, we all have bad days.

Answer (score 1):

We already had the **[Great Rep Recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)**, I don't think we need to go around killing badges also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want badges to basically upgrade. The way the system works is that it can't revoke badges easily, so it probably won't work too well with the current code.