# How does daily reputation cap immunity work?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day (although accepted answers and bounty awards are immune to this limit).

How does this immunity work? I have two scenarios to explain what I mean:

**Day 1**

1. You get 20 upvotes.
2. You get 20 accepted answers.

This will earn you 500 reputation, since the accepted answers are immune to the daily cap.

**Day 2**

1. You get 20 accepted answers.
2. You get 20 upvotes.

Now, will this earn you 300 or 500 reputation?

Comment: Did you mean to have more differences in your examples? (I'm not sure where 300 comes from...)  In both cases you'd get 500 reputation.

Comment: @Nick: On the second day he gains 300 rep through accepts first and is thus already over 200 rep for the day when his first answer is upvoted. In the old days this would mean that none of the upvotes would count, so the total rep would have been 300.

Comment: @sepp2k - Ah I see, no the order doesn't matter...the accepts just don't factor into the 200 at all.

Comment: There are simply two buckets. In the capped bucket you put received up/downvotes. In the uncapped buckets you put bounties, accepted answers, the cost of downvotes you gave to others,...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the olden days it used to be so that you'd only gain 300 rep on day 2.

However these days it doesn't matter whether your answers are accepted before or after you hit the cap, so you'll gain 500.

Comment: Related: [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010).