# Got serially downvoted after hitting the cap, but did not get everything back

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

This question spawned from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161211/155556)

---

On Decmber 27th I hit the rep cap and any further upvotes were **not** counted:

[image]

**After** I hit the cap I was serially downvoted, but yet any further votes for me were *still* not counted.

On the 28th, the serial upvoting was reversed, but I still "lost" the rep cap from the 27th, and the 60 upvote re, which should have basically nullified (in and of itself) the downvoting.

What happened? Have I stumbled upon a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: See [Why do the up-votes after reaching daily rep cap not contribute to compensate the subsequent down-votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160121)

Comment: @TimStone That does not answer the question of why this was not even considered as a "rep cap day" (especially for the hat).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full breakdown of your reputation history, as I see it on your profile:

[image: Full breakdown]

All of these numbers add up to **+233**. I can't account for the other 2 reputation, nor can I verify that those are actually all the downvotes that got reversed, but it does appear you are still rep-capped for that day. There is no more reputation to give to you.

Keep in mind that those votes *may have* been giving you reputation. But when serially voting gets reversed, the day affected by it is *completely recalculated* to make sure you get all the reputation you deserved (and didn't deserve).