# Upvotes after cap + downvote don't compensate for the downvote

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160121/162102), upvotes received after a downvote should give "partial credit" up to the cap of 200.  If so, what happened [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/325/monica-cellio?tab=reputation)?  On Jan 14 I had 27 upvotes, 1 downvote, and 7 of those upvotes came after the downvote -- yet the total for the day shows 198, not 200.

[image: rep history]

I believe this used to show 200 -- it's a number you tend to notice. :-)  Also, my rep on that site mysteriously went down by 2 today (which is what prompted me to be looking at the history).

I'm not worried about 2 points one way or the other, but I'd like to know what happened.

Comment: Did you check http://workplace.stackexchange.com/reputation ? Does it tally?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at there, but I see " 2013-01-14 rep +200  = 4725 " -- so according to that I was awarded 200 that day?  That matches my memory and doesn't match the current report/stat.

Comment: Yes, it means that (that is the reputation audit page). Does the number at the very end of the page match your current reputation?

Comment: It matches the number currently being reported as my rep.  So here's the weird thing: earlier in the day my rep was 5932, I downvoted twice and saw it go to 5930, and later one downvoted post was removed and I received 4 upvotes (answers).  That should add up to 5971; instead it's 5969.  The rep history suggests that whatever happened on this day in the screenshot is the source of the difference, but I'm not sure how that happened.  And I guess whatever happened happened today.

Comment: The definitive source is the audit page. The reputation on the profile is not always... accurate. Do you have the "show removed posts" checkbox checked on the profile page?

Comment: I do have that checked.  Ok, so weirdness in the profile that may someday get synched up again with the audit data?  That works.  (You should put that in an answer.)

Comment: Still looks like a bug, does it?

Comment: It looks like a bug; is it a known bug and this is a dup?  (I didn't find a dup when searching before posting.  @Oded's comment suggests this is known behavior.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That downvote was reversed on January 16, which caused all your events on the day where the original downvote occurred to be re-calculated. You have 20 votes there that earned you +10 reputation each. All is well.

[image: Undownvote on Jan 16]

Comment: Ok, so rep is correct but there's apparently a bug in the per-day breakdown on the rep page?  On that day I would have expected to see +2 from the next upvote, and for that to be reversed alongside the downvote when the vote was removed two days later.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: The system does not award you 2 reputation for an undownvote, it *reverses* the -2 from the original downvote. Technically the -2 never occurred as far as the system is concerned, and there was never any reason to award an additional 2 reputation on another capped event. The events indicating the -2 and subsequent +2 are only there to indicate why your reputation went down by 2 and then back up by 2 later on.

Comment: @animuson See how this same issue comes up again and again? I know that this is a hard problem, and that it all makes sense after your explanation, but the number of users who misunderstand it is going to grow until the issue becomes visually self-explanatory. One way to make it self-explanatory would be through adding "auto-generated animuson's answers" on the day when a vote is undone: add a link to Jan-16 event to the list of events of Feb-5, showing where the +2 came from.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I actually [have a proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversal-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes) that could cover this quite well. I'll submit a modification to it sometime to cover this specific issue too.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that's right, I have already upvoted your proposal! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The way the profile page is generated and the data it shows doesn't always tally up with how things occurred. Deletions of posts are particularly an issue. Perhaps this will get fixed one day.

The definitive place to audit your reputation is on the reputation audit page - for The Workplace that would be:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: It's actually calculated correctly. ;P

Comment: @animuson - Yeah, in this case... Though it can get out of sync.