# At the maximum 200 rep/day, are down votes deducted from uncredits or taken from the 200?

Tags: support, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

If I have reached the 200 per day reputation point, and have not had 50, or whatever, reps added - are any downvotes then deducted from my stated reputation or do they deduct from my 'unpaid' credits ?

Answer (score 4):

In the following order of events:

- rep cap at 200 (say 25 upvotes)
- 2 upvotes (no additional rep, as rep cap)
- 1 downvote (-2 rep)

The result will be rep of 198 for the day.

If any additional upvotes would happen after that, the rep gained would be 2, to reach the rep cap.

Comment: Yes, but if I had 200, then gained another 50, and _then_ got a downer, do I have 200 [48] or do I have 198 [50] ?

Comment: @oded - What is the logic behind this? It seems counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Again. 198. That is **exactly** what I illustrated in my answer, no?

Comment: @Yaron - order of events. You don't get "credit" for past actions. It is also a lot easier to reason about reputation this way, when calculating it.

Comment: The [answer on the dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160121/152859) is much better. Water, buckets, overflow. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Downvotes first deduct reputation from the 200 you have.**

Later upvotes on the same day will refund that lost reputation.

Reputation gained from bounties or accepted answers will not be affected.