# Daily reputation cap doesn't account for reputation * loss* due to bounty awarded?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

There are many Q&A's around this and the best explanation of daily cap model is from this answer that uses [the bucket analogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160121/308746). It is an old answer but gives a good understanding.

My confusion is in applying this model to my situation yesterday.

- On 31/12/2019, I awarded a bounty to [*my question*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219821/131553), since it became eligible for bounty (2 days after posting it). Subsequently, I got more upvotes (including one accept) which exceeded the daily cap of 200.
- I am confused about this-loss of reputation due to bounty awarded by me *preceeded* subsequent gain of reputation so going by the bucket analogy, I should have my rep adjusted accordingly and those 6 up votes (at the bottom of table) should have been credited (rep should have been 177 instead of 117),  `/reputation` shows this

```
2 219845 (10) 
1 219884 (2) 
2 170717 (10) 
2 219621 (10) 
2 219845 (10)
2 219845 (10)
2 218537 (10) 
2 219845 (10) 
2 219892 (10) 
2 219845 (10)
8 219821 (-100)
 2 219845 (10) 
2 219621 (10) 
2 219845 (10)
 2 219821 (10) 
2 219845 (10)
 2 219845 (10) 
2 219845 (10) 
2 219912 (10)
 1 219912 (15) 
2 219845 (10) 
2 219845 (10) 
2 219892 [10] 
2 219845 [0] 
2 219621 [0] 
2 219845 [0] 
2 219845 [0] 
2 219845 [0] 
2 219845 [0] 
-- 2019-12-31 rep +117 = 27089 --
```

It is not the 6 votes I am bothered about, it is more about trying to correct my understanding  or have I stumbled upon an anomaly?

Comment: Because a bounty is not reputation loss in the normal sense. You gained the max of 200 rep from votes, a bounty is  **not** a vote.

Comment: @Luuklag seems to make sense but I wonder if such occurrence has been accounted for or the reasoning you give explicitly mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you cite only relates to *capped* reputation, and not to exempt reputation.

In short, there are two daily buckets that your reputation events fall into: *capped* reputation and *exempt* reputation. Rep changes from votes and suggested edits fall into the *capped* bucket, while all other changes (e.g. accepted answers, giving and receiving bounties, user removals, voting reversals, etc.) fall into the *exempt* bucket.

The *capped* bucket works exactly like the other answer you cited describes: you earn reputation toward filling the bucket, and any extra rep beyond that will just overflow. The *exempt* bucket, on the other hand, works entirely differently: it is of infinite size, and as such never overflows.

Your reputation in a given day is the sum of those two buckets.

Put all together, this means that you can end up capping out at below 200 on a given day, if you have a net negative exempt reputation on that day. As the bounty offer rep change deducted 100 rep from the *exempt* bucket, this does not affect your capped reputation for the day, which is still a maximum of 200. Therefore, you saw yourself hitting the cap at 100 reputation (200 capped plus -100 exempt).

<sub>Note that in the past, there was indeed a single bucket that all events fell into, which had a cap of 200, with subsequent exempt changes simply overflowing into the bucket but still granting you rep. As an example, if your earned a 50-rep bounty early in the day, you could only earn 150 more rep from votes before capping out, but if you already capped out on votes before earning the bounty, you'd receive 250 overall rep for the day. However, this was later changed to the current model above.</sub>

Comment: +1. I was also thinking on lines of two buckets after reading Robert's answer. And you came up with more a cogent explanation. I agree with your view and logic *but*  I feel this should have been documented either in the rules or as a community mod validation so that it supplements the rule book. Or am I being a nitpick? ((I don't t think so)

Comment: Thanks. I wish somebody would post a canonical answer including yours, the answer cited and the rationale for capping as mentioned by Jeff on the linked side bar

Answer (score 5):

You can earn up to 200 rep per day from edits and upvotes. Any more reputation gains from those activities is capped.

Separately you can gain or lose rep from bounties either by receiving them (gain) or creating them (loss) and having your answer accepted. This rep gain/loss does not affect the former edit/upvote calculation in any way.

The system calculates the edit/upvote rep gain, caps it if necessary and then adds on (or removes) the accept and bounty rep.

If the system allowed creating of a bounty to result in more upvote rep being awarded then it would allow high rep individuals (those that get > 200 rep from upvotes every day) to award free bounties because any bounties they created would immediately be soaked up by the excess upvotes they passively get from all their good answers.

Comment: +1. Firstly, just as bounties received don't count so do bounties awarded don't count - logical. Secondly, the last paragraph also is convincing. What I am looking for is a mention in the daily cap rules or some community mod endorsing this view.